# browsersync + gulp not injecting css - only reloading

Tags: npm, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

I have recently moved to using BrowserSync, I followed their [gulp guide](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp) and tweaked a few things to solve some issues I was having, however now whilst it works, it appears to reload the page every time rather than inject the CSS.

My gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'js/dev/main/**/*.js',
        // We have to set the bootstrap lines separately as some need to go before others
        'js/dev/bootstrap/alert.js',
        'js/dev/bootstrap/collapse.js',
        'js/dev/bootstrap/tooltip.js',
        'js/dev/bootstrap/popover.js',
        'js/dev/bootstrap/tab.js',
        'js/dev/bootstrap/transition.js',
    ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});

gulp.task('uglify', ['scripts'], function() {
    return gulp.src('js/scripts.js')
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify({
            mangle: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});

// create a task that ensures the `uglify` task is complete before
// reloading browsers
gulp.task('js-watch', ['uglify'], function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

/* Creates the standard version */

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(postcss([
                autoprefixer({
                    browsers: [
                        'last 4 Chrome versions',
                        'last 4 Firefox versions',
                        'last 4 Edge versions',
                        'last 2 Safari versions',
                        'ie >= 10',
                        '> 1.49%',
                        'not ie <= 9'
                    ],
                    cascade: false
                }),
            ]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream(({match: 'css/**/*.css'})));
});

/* Creates the minified version */

gulp.task('css-minify', ['styles'], function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass({
                outputStyle: 'compact' // Options: nested, expanded, compact, compressed
            }).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(postcss([
                autoprefixer({
                    browsers: [
                        'last 4 Chrome versions',
                        'last 4 Firefox versions',
                        'last 4 Edge versions',
                        'last 2 Safari versions',
                        'ie >= 10',
                        '> 1.49%',
                        'not ie <= 9'
                    ],
                    cascade: false
                }),
            ]))
            .pipe(cleanCSS({
                advanced: false,
                aggressiveMerging: false
            }))
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        open: 'external',
        proxy: "bmmedia.dev",
        host: 'bmmedia.dev',
        // port: 5000,
        browser: "chrome",
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'js-watch', 'css-minify'], function() {
    gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss', 'js/dev/**/*.js'], ['js-watch', 'css-minify']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['js-watch', 'css-minify']);
```

Notice my `watch` task, this was the most recent change I did as I was having the problem specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580839/browser-sync-typeerror-args-cb-is-not-a-function/36873752), and I solved it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41140218/472501), however now whilst it works fine, it appears to only reload, rather than inject.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

**Edit:**

I just realized it was reloading every time because I was running `js-watch` every time there was a change, even to `.scss` files, so I changed it to this:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'js-watch', 'css-minify'], function() {
    gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss'], ['css-minify']);
    gulp.watch(['js/dev/**/*.js'], ['js-watch']);
});
```

However now it doesn't inject OR reload when a `.scss` file changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have fixed it...

My `watch` task I changed to:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss'], ['css-minify']);
    gulp.watch(['js/dev/**/*.js'], ['js-watch']);
});
```

Then in my `styles` task I changed this line:

```
.pipe(browserSync.stream(({match: 'css/**/*.css'})));
```

to:

```
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
```

Not sure why it wasn't finding the CSS changes, all I know is it now seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try just watching the compiled output files.

```
Dest/css/styles.css
Dest/js/my.js
```

Any changes to a sass / js module would reflect in the final css / js output files. Browser reloading will only fire when the css/js compilation has completed, rather than trying to reload as the sass /js bundles compile.

Also, take a look at Gulp-newer. It can be used for checking / triggering tasks if the final output file (dest/css/styles.css) has been changed relative to the files that made it (src/sass/**.scss).

This is also very handy for images (no need to minify them on each build, only if newer) any other checks you need to perform only if something has changed can also be added.

Comment: You mean detach the `browser-sync` task from the `watch` task so it doesn't attempt to run as the bundles complete? Also, thanks for the tip about `gulp-newer`, looks like a good plugin. :)

Comment: .pipe(reload({stream:true}));  should be placed at the end of each script process you want to make sure refreshes the browser, so there is no need to "watch" the browser reload task during the main watch task fn.

Comment: Well, I'm not "watching" the task - it just runs when the `watch` runs; but since the `watch` task is a process that idles waiting for changes, I don't know for sure, but I assume it only runs the once and then when changes happen it runs the requested tasks, which doesn't include the `browser-sync` task, as that should only be ran (initiated) when the `watch` task is ran itself.